# How to not going through openvpn tunnel for a specific port

Tags: arch-linux, iptables, openvpn

After long hours of digging and many tries I still cannot figure out how to not have a traffic on a given port going through the openvpn tunnel. Below my setup:

```
(enp0s25)<ovpn server>(tun0) <--> (tun0)<ovpn client>(enp2s0) <--> app connecting on port 10011
```

The ovpn server is configured to push the route setup to the client with `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` so that all the traffic is redirected through the tunnel which is what I want and is working perfectly, except I want the tcp port 10011 not going through the tunnel...

The kernel routing table main of `<ovpn client>` is:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.88.9 dev tun0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0
128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.88.9 dev tun0  # not sure why it's there..
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.29
192.168.88.0/24 via 192.168.88.9 dev tun0
192.168.88.9 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.88.10
```

Here is my latest try on `<ovpn client>`:

1. Define a routing table openvpn

   ```
   default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0
   192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.29
   ```
2. Define the rule `1000:   from all fwmark 0x64 lookup openvpn`
3. Define the following iptables mangle rules:

   ```
   -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 10011 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x64/0xffffffff
   -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 10011 -j LOG --log-prefix "(OUTPUT) fwmark 100: "
   ```

The idea (which might be bad) is to have the `<ovpn client> --> app connecting on port 10011` communications not going back and forth through the tunnel because of the routing table entry `0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.88.9 dev tun0` but use the routing table openvpn which is a very basic "local network" routing table.

I use mangle OUTPUT because it comes just after the process sends the data on port 10011 and before POSTROUTING so I thought it would be the right chain to use.

When starting openvpn on `<ovpn client>` and trying to connect on port 10011 I cannot see any system logs generated by the LOG iptables rule whereas with openvpn stopped I see the logs and everything works fine.

Maybe the source IP of the outgoing traffic to the app is the one of tun0 interface so the routing is broken somewhere..